# why does the counter variable reset to old value within the same function?

Tags: python, recursion, nested-lists

I am trying to get the count of all items in the nested lists. while the code traverse through all items, the counter gets set to only non-nested list items. what is happenning and how to I correct this code?

```
def countarr(arr,count):
    
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return count

    else:
        
        if type(arr[0]) != list:
            count += 1
            print(arr[0],count)
        else:
            print ("inner")
            countarr(arr[0],count)

    return countarr(arr[1:],count)
    
count=0
arr=[1,2,[[4,5]],8,[7,4,5,6],12,34]
print("Answer: ",countarr(arr, count))
```

Comment: Note that it's recommended to use `isinstance(x, list)` rather than `type(x) == list`

Comment: When you make your recursive call `countarr(arr[0],count)`, you're discarding the return value of that call. Presumably you want to do something like `count = countarr(arr[0],count)` or `count += countarr(arr[0],count)`

Comment: Note that when you pass `count` as parameter in a function call, you're actually passing a ***copy*** of `count`. A new local variable is created in the function call, with the value that you passed, and locally that variable is named `count`, but if you update the variable named `count` inside the recursive call, it doesn't update the variable named `count` in the current call.

Comment: Thank you so much. I  originally misunderstood the reason why it is gets discarded. I thought the countarr() call when the arr[0] type is a list discards the updates because its updates are local to it. I think  I now see the correct reason. This inner function calls the the main recursion function when arr[0] is list. Count keeps getting  updated as  it is passed as a parameter. But the last line of the outer recursion returns the variable to the inner call but it is not storing this return value, & so discarded. Is this right? Also the scope of this stored count is the outer function. Right?

Comment: I recommend not passing `count` as a parameter at all, since it is confusing you and is not useful at all in this case. Instead, you can do: `def countarr(arr): if len(arr) == 0: return 0 elif isinstance(arr[0], list): return countarr(arr[0]) + countarr(arr[1:]) else: return 1 + countarr(arr[1:])`

Comment: Or alternatively: `def countarr(arr): count = len(arr); for x in arr: if isinstance(x, list): count += countarr(x); return count` (with the last `return` outside of the `for`-loop, not inside). This version is actually much better, because it avoids using `arr[1:]`, which is inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` is a variable of type `int`. When passing an `int` as parameter to a function in python, only the value is passed, not the actual variable. So, when the recursive call "modifies `count`", it actually modifies ***a copy*** of the variable, not the original. So, the original is not updated.

Furthermore, when you do the recursive call: `countarr(arr[0])`, you're not using the return value of that call. You can simply add `count =` in front of the recursive call, to retrieve the returned value of the recursive call:

```py
def countarr0(arr,count):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return count
    else: 
        if not isinstance(arr[0], list):
            count += 1
        else:
            count = countarr0(arr[0], count)
    return countarr0(arr[1:], count)
    
arr=[1,2,[[4,5]],8,[7,4,5,6],12,34]
print("Answer: ",countarr0(arr, 0))
# Answer:  11
```

However, passing an argument `count` to the recursive call is not really useful. The recursive call doesn't need to know the current value of `count`. The recursive call should just count how many elements are in the nested sublist, and we'll add its return value to our current count:

```py
def countarr1(arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        count = 0
        if isinstance(arr[0], list):
            count += countarr1(arr[0])
        else:
            count += 1
        count += countarr1(arr[1:])
        return count

arr=[1,2,[[4,5]],8,[7,4,5,6],12,34]
print("Answer: ",countarr1(arr))
# Answer:  11
```

Note that using recursion to navigate the sublists is a good idea; but using recursion to iterate on the list is a bad idea in python. In python, recursion is much slower than `for`-loops; in addition, when you write `arr[1:]`, a whole new copy of the array is made! That's terribly inefficient. Instead, we can use a loop to iterate on the list:

```py
def countarr2(arr):
    count = 0
    for x in arr:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            count += countarr2(x)
        else:
            count += 1
    return count

arr=[1,2,[[4,5]],8,[7,4,5,6],12,34]
print("Answer: ",countarr2(arr))
# Answer:  11
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables don't magically reset. They only are set to the value you give it. Modifying the value of a local variable does not affect the value of another variable in another function, even if it has the same name. Take the following example:

```
def foo(count):
   print(count)
   count += 1 
   print(count)

def bar()
   count = 0
   print(count)
   foo(count)
   print(count)

bar()
```

Recursion is the same. Each recursive function call has its own copies of local variables just in the same way `foo()` and `bar()` each have a variable named count that are independent of each other.

To fix the recursive function, just return the value of `count` from every possible `if...else` branch. You already do this in two of the branches, but you only print the value in two other branches and don't return it.

Comment: Thanks. What is confusing for me is, as you see from the printouts, the count survives when it enters the nested list and through the recursive calls but gets reset when it exits the nested list. I am teaching myself programming and would appreciate if you could give some hints as to why this happens.

Comment: @ArNY I'm not sure what "enters the nested list" mean. You can't "enter" a list. Or at least that's not a common use of the word "enter" in the programming community. To talk about this more concretely, I suggest editing your question to include output from your program and then frame your question based on which parts of that output you are confused about. This will make your question more concrete.

Comment: @ArNY With that said, I suggest you read more about so-called "variable scope" in python. Understanding why my example gives the output it does is the first step. Then seeing how that same concept applies to your recursive function will help you understand what's going on.

Comment: @ArNY In your recursive example, each call to `countarr()` has its own `count` variable. When you `return` to a particular `countarr()` frame, its `count` will have the same value it had before you called recursively. The value of `count` doesn't "reset". Rather there are multiple `count` variables which each have their own value.

Comment: Thank you. This helps. I will read more about this.

Comment: I see what is happenning